# DataGridViewRow thread safety in Windows Forms .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, datagridviewrow

In my continual quest to better understand thread-safe programming in .NET, I can't seem to get clarity on a question, so I'm hoping that someone on SO might be able to assist.

I understand that a Windows Form Control should not be accessed by a non-UI/worker thread directly without using Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke.  However, what about in the case of a DataGridViewRow object?  If I understand correctly, the DataGridViewRow object itself is NOT a Control.  However, it's normal usage is to add it to a DataGridView Control.  Does this affect the way that we need to interact with the DataGridViewRow object?

For example, if you have a DataGridViewRow object added to a DataGridView Control, is it safe to access the DataGridViewRow object directly?  Or is it the case that since it has been added to the DataGridView Control, it therefore must only be accessed by using DataGridView.Invoke.

Note, in this example we are not modifying the value and instead are only reading it.  Does this even matter?

```
    //since we are passing a DataGridViewRow object and NOT the actual DataGridView Control object, is it safe to call this method directly from a worker thread?  Note, in this code example we are NOT modifying the value and instead we are only reading it.  If were WERE modifying the value, would it make a difference?
    string retrieveColumn1Value (DataGridViewRow row)
    {
        string column1String = row.Cells[column1].Value.ToString(); 
        return column1String;
    }

    //or is it the case that since the DataGridViewRow object has been added to our DataGridView Control, that we have to use this method instead to ensure thread-safety?
    string retrieveColumn1ValueWithInvoke (DataGridViewRow row)
    {
        string column1String = (string)dataGridView1.Invoke(new retrieveColumnValuesDelegate(lookupColumnValues), new object[] { row });
        return column1String;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), instance methods are not thread safe.  I don't know that DataGridViewRow has any useful static members, so I'd say you should use Invoke().

More importantly, can you change things so you're UI thread does all manipulation of the UI, and leave other threads for background processing?  That's the best way to handle multi-threading.